# how to commit 'commit log' itself in same svn version?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, pre-commit

It might sound unnecessary, but let me explain my problem first. Probably then it would make sense.

Few artists keep updating images based on clients' change requests. An artist makes changes accordingly and commits with proper 'commit messages'. Just before actual commit, I want to create a text file with image properties like size and all the 'commit messages'. And then this file would be committed itself. So basically some sort of pre-commit  processing is required. Even though most of the artists are not very comfortable with svn, they can always see what changes were made last time to the image via simple text file. So artists only do update and commit with svn.

How this could be done?

Are there any better alternatives?

Comment: So you're saying that your artists are able to understand and use svn update and svn commit but are unable to comprehend svn log?

Comment: @Mark, our artists do update and commit 'mechanically' and ask for something simpler all the time. May be we should hire more skilled artists, but that's irrelevant to the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This could probably be done with hooks etc. as you say. I would go the other way and provide a script/program/webpage that extracts information from the commit log and displays it when required, as a kind of user friendly wrapper around `svn log`.